# exact folder to import csv to python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pycharm, anaconda

I'm a python beginner. I've installed Anaconda and Pycharm.

I would like to import a `.csv` as in this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('FremontBridge.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
data.head()
```

but it's not clear to me in which folder I have to put the `.csv` file mentioned, in order to use this code.

Is there an option to choose a customized folder?

Comment: You can just pass a fully qualified path `pd.read_csv(r'c:/my_folder/some_other_folder/FremontBridge.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)`

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you put the .csv file in the same folder as your script as the path is considered relative.

Otherwise, you may pass the absolute path as a string.

```
filepath = "C:/Users/your_user/Documents/whatever/your_file.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
```

---

**Edit: What follows is obsolete. Today, I strongly recommend the use of [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).**

Since you mention being a beginner, I'd like to introduce you to [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

```
filepath = os.path.abspath("C:/Users/your_user/Documents/whatever/your_file.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
```

It can do clean joins and automatically manage trailing slashes in an OS-independent way (useless in this example).

```
filedir = os.path.abspath("C:/Users/your_user/Documents/whatever")
filename = "your_file.csv"
filepath = os.join(filedir, filename)
```

Anyway, it is a nice habit to use it for path management, rather than using string concatenations for joins, for instance.

(Python 3.4 introduces [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which is practical, but not included in former Python version (it has to be installed as an external lib).)

Comment: thanks but I don't understand in which folder I have to put the .csv file, like C:\Anaconda ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the absolute path, as described in the doc:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table